# I need to add payment method for customer in customer_register_success event, Magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, register

I need to add a default payment method for customers, is it possible to do it in time this event customer_register_success ? I added a drop-down list in the registration form and show active payment methods, when a customer chooses a payment method, it should be added as a payment method

OR , I want to put this block in reg form

[image]

Comment: do you mean you need to save the payment method selection into custom attribute? Or custom table or what?

Comment: I have products in the registration form and when the customer chooses the product he must choose and the payment method because the order is fulfilled in the registry , Could I correctly describe what I want? thanks

Comment: so you want to set that payment method to set as checkout

Comment: Dhiren Vasoya yes